# Could chicken meat ever be safe when pink?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, meat, chicken-breast, thermometer

I have cooked chicken breasts today and they read 83c (safe is 73c) with a ThermoWorks Thermopop (best company in the industry). When I sliced them they had small pink strips on the inside. What does it mean? Was the chicken safe? Is it impossible for chicken to be both slightly pink and safe?

Comment: How did you cook the chicken? And have you verified the accuracy of your thermometer?

Comment: also see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11526/ and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11433 as well as (indirectly) our basic guide on food safety: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info. In short: visual changes are not related to food safety, temperature is. The looks of food are a folklore method for recognizing doneness.

Comment: Also make sure that you're using the thermometer correctly; see here http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/how-do-you-correctly-use-a-meat-thermometer